# Installing DRBD on XEN CentOS 5.8 (Stable)

Tags: centos, xen, drbd, pacemaker, corosync

I am trying for days to achieve HA with fault tolerance between my existing two XEN VPS's one located in Tokyo and the other located in US (both have the same setup and the same configurations, I am considering Pacemaker, Corosync, DRBD and Stonith but I am facing hell since both systems are up and running (in production) and I can't effort data loss of any kind.

```
/dev/sda1 (formatted in ext3 and mounted as /)
/var/tmp (formatted in ext3 and mounted as /tmp)
```

I know that DRBD needs it's own unmounted dedicated partition before installation to use for data synchronization and metadata thats why I shrinked the root partition on both servers but I am logically lost because we're talking about webservers here with a lot of running services including but not limited to (Apache, MySQL, FTP...etc)

```
/dev/sda1 (formatted in ext3 and mounted as /)
/dev/sda2 (unmounted unformatted partition)
/var/temp (formatted in ext3 and mounted as /tmp)
```

So what should I do starting from this point, how can I move all these services to the new unmounted partitions without affecting the running servers, how can I secure the communications between the two servers with the minimum delay possible and if VPN is the answer how can I achieve it and am I on the right track regarding (Pacemaker, Corosync, DRBD and Stonith) or there's still something missing I am not aware of and are they the best choice for my existing setup or not, I did my homework and I tried a lot before asking, it's my first experience on such setup and I really need your technical experience and recommendations and maybe a technical path for me to take to achieve my goal.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read my question and have a great day :))

Comment: Your scenario sounds like you want the replicated partition to be mounted on both sides at the same time, is that correct? DRBD doesn't support that, with DRBD you can only have a master side and a slave side, the slave side cannot be mounted. To be precise, that's not a problem of DRBD actually, but of the file systems that run on top of it, because they are designed to be in full control of their underlying block devices. reference: http://www.drbd.org/home/mirroring/

Comment: No I am trying to achieve Active/Passive setup, I want a primary slave kind of situation to be exact!

Comment: It's very hard to answer your question, because you have a whole bunch of questions and not much details. So regarding moving data to the new partitions, at least for MySQL this will quite certainly require a down time of the service. For the webserver you might be able to get around the downtime, by copying the files to the new partition, changing the server config, and then deleting the files from the old partition, but even for the webserver it would certainly be more convenient to get a planned down time for it. Are your setups locally redundant or only between the continents?

Comment: I have no problem having 24 hours downtime as long as I get this setup up running and I don't screw the existing setup but the real question is, how can I move these services?

Comment: Let's assume all of the data that you need to move is in `/var`. So that's what you could do: 1) shut down all services that have open files in `/var`, you can find with the command `lsof +D /var`. 2) mount the new partition somewhere else, f.e `/var2` 3) copy everything from `/var` to `/var2` and make sure the permissions don't change (f.e. `cp -dra /var/* /var2/`) 4) `umount /var2`, then rename `/var` into `mv /var /var3` (to not delete yet) 5) mount the new partition on `/var` 6) bring services back and test 7) if everything is working, delete /var3

Comment: Your assumption is absolutely right, all my data are in var and configurations in /etc shouldn't be synchronized between the 2 nodes because they differ, brilliant! Now I want to secure the communications between the 2 nodes with the minimum delay, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Security and minimum delay is a tradeoff. Maximum security usually brings along some overhead, minimum delay implies less security. I guess an IPSec VPN like for example Openswan would make sense, but I don't know your priorities

Comment: My priorities are secured connection between the 2 nodes, I can handle the delay as long as I have a secured connection and is (Pacemaker, Corosync, DRBD and Stonith) perfect for my setup or am I am missing something else and are they the best for my setup or there's better alternatives?

Comment: My do you need dual-primary?

Comment: because I am running roundrobbin DNS, those servers are very busy and I need the shared storage to be mounted on both servers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - this is doable. Be aware that you need to install

- kmod-drbd83-xen
- drbd83

I do not recommend using older versions of drbd.

But I would use a different approach regarding your disk-layout:

- Use one of your partitions - I recommend using the last one - (sda2 in your case) as PV for LVM
- set the type of the partition to LVM
- Initiate is as PV
- make a VG with that PV
- make a meta-LV for drbd-bitmaps
- use a separate LV for every drbd-replicated device
- map one LV to each drbd-device

Now for the drbd-setup:

- If possible use async-mode (protocol A) and use a large buffer-size (8 MB) for writes within your drbd-setup.
- take a close look at your bandwidth setting for the replication - do not saturate the link
- use a good after **[split-brain-setup](https://serverfault.com/a/567979/77281)**

Comment: I did exactly what you mentioned but I am using protocol C and my bandwidth between the 2 links is 2MBits, both machines are restarted daily (dual-split-brain) because of the link load is too high, my disk read/write is horrible 200MB copy takes 6 hours, any ideas?

Comment: @user204252 The latency of protocol C is killing you. You should really switch to protocol A and raise the write-buffer. I also added a link to my recommended sb-setup.

Comment: I wish I can use protocol A or B but I am on a dual-primary mode :// any idea?